# Can i download jboss Eap zip as maven dependency and using assembly will copy that zip in one of my folder(fileset) structure

Tags: java, maven, jboss

i need the dependency for jboss EAP zip so i will take that zip and using my assembly will copy my one of module which is war file and this jboss zip in single fileset and after that using installer i can deploy(unzip) this jboss eap and deploy my application in that.
Can any one have idea how to take that zip file or suggest Dependency.

Comment: Are you asking how you can embed EAP into another piece of software?

Comment: yes i have application where i need EAP as my server but i am using assembly for folder structure and script i am using for start EAP and configure as i want.